# Error while building services in liferay 6.2

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay-6, liferay-ide, spring-portlet-mvc, liferay-service-builder

While building the services in the liferay 6.2, am getting the error like it has dependency of "e/hunsicker/jalopy/Jalopy". Not sure whether it really needed its dependency or am missing out some things. Am using spring MVC as the underlying portlet framework.

```
<service-builder package-path="com.san.portlet.record">
<author>San</author>
<namespace>po_san</namespace>
<entity name="LMSBook" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />
<column name="bookTitle" type="String" />
<column name="author" type="String" />
<column name="createDate" type="Date" />
</entity>
```

The error while building is

```
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource aQute/bnd/ant/taskdef.properties. It could not be found.
build-service:
[jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\san\portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Record-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
[delete] Deleting: C:\san\portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Record-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar.manifest
[java] Java Result: 1
[delete] Deleting: C:\san\portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Record-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
[delete] Deleting: C:\san\portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Record-portlet\ServiceBuilder.temp
    [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/san/portal/server/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
    [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/san/portal/server/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
    [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/san/portal/server/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
    [echo] Building LMSBook
    [echo] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/hunsicker/jalopy/Jalopy
    [echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:390)
    [echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:365)
    [echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._createActionableDynamicQuery(ServiceBuilder.java:1745)
    [echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:731)
    [echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:228)
    [echo] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy
    [echo]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    [echo]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [echo]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    [echo]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [echo]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [echo]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [echo]  ... 5 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\selva\portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:249: Service Builder generated exceptions.
```

Comment: Do you have jalopy jar somewhere in skd?

Comment: Yes the jalopy dependency is present in ivy.xml. I have download the latest version. it is working now.

Comment: please make this quastion solved

Answer (score 0):

the jalopy dependency is present in ivy.xml. I have download the latest version. it is working now